# ERROR: Specified config file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist

Tags: linux, chef

I keep getting the following when trying to install Chef:

```
[root@COMMAND ~]# chef-server-ctl org-create chef "Chef Software, Inc." -f /tmp/chef.key
ERROR: Specified config file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist!
```

I am following this guide:

```
https://docs.chef.io/install_dk.html
```

Where am I going wrong in trying to setup the Chef Server? I've search and tried the reconfigure and other options mentioned.

This a CentOS 7 machine VM running as a container in proxmox with 512MB RAM if that means anything.

I've installed version 12.03 as people said that worked for the Chef Server and the latest as well but I keep getting the same results when trying to setup the Chef Server by the guide.

EDIT:
Rebuilt the VM several times and set RAM to 2GBs same result.

Is it always this hard to setup a central Chef server to send management commands from to other servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the ctl commands on the machine where Chef Server is installed, not a workstation. You need at least 4GB of RAM for a Chef Server, though 8 is highly recommended. If just getting started with Chef either use Hosted Chef for now or use chef-solo.